# Parse.com Cannot read property 'objectId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm encountering a strange error when receiving an object with `Parse.Query`:

```
var installationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
installationQuery.each(function(installation) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(installation));
    console.log(installation.objectId);
    console.log(installation.get("objectId"));
}
```

The first log shows that I receive a perfectly normal `Installation` object:

```
{"appIdentifier":"XXX","appName":"XXX",...,"objectId":"XXXXXXXXXX"}
```

But the other two give me this error:

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectId' of undefined
```

How do I extract the `objectId` of the `installation` object?

Comment: And what's the output of `console.log(installation);`?

Comment: It's `[object Object]`

Comment: Björn already suggested a solution that works. Since it was clear from my first console log that there was a healthy object with content that I needed, it was just a matter of accessing that.

Comment: Please console the list of keys in that object, using a for loop `for(var key in installation) console.log(key);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objectId` can be accessed via the `id` field of the object, it is a little bit counter-intuitive but that should work.

Comment: I knew this had to be a simple solution :)